# How do i animate a sphere, that behaves kinde like slime, that gets thrown/fired and explode, when it hits something?

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

EDIT: So, im working now on a new animation and i need help. I want a sphere to behave kinda like slime, it is supposed to hit a certain place and explode there. With that explosion, it has to cover the camera view with the exploded sphere. But i don't have an idea how to realize that. I tried some stuff with the Soft Body physiks, but i never used it, so the result was pure crap what. Maybe someone of you out there knows, what exactly i need to do in this situation.

EDIT: I figured out a solution, i am not realy satisfied with it, but i will keep playing with the settings. What i basically did was, i made a sphere, deformed it a bit and enabled "Soft Body" and Collision" for it. The target of that sphere also has "Collision" enabled. On the "Soft Body" settings, i disabled "Soft Body Goal", so the sphere got influenced by gravity. Then on the "Collision-setting" of the sphere, i increased the Stickiness Value up to 10, also on the target. Now i created a Wind-Force Field, i placed it under the sphere and made it blow (with the help of keyframes) the sphere to its target. Now i am trying to get better results with playing in the "Soft Body" and "Collision" settings.

Comment: Google "blender fluid simulation droplet"

Comment: The thing is, that Paint drop is animated with keyframes. I want it to splash at a certain point and stand still there, like a ball made out of slime, that splashes at a window and sticks on it. Can i still solve that problem with fluid simulations?

Comment: ah, in that case look at animating Metaballs

Comment: On the first look, i think that could help me, i will try it tomorrow. Thank you very much rob.

Comment: So, i've been searching now for that, but i couldn't find something, i can use. Non of those tutorials, i saw, show me, what i want to do.

Comment: The fluid simulation has a lot of options and should do what you need but will be time consuming to get right and tweak. The Metaballs option is the other extreme, you can easily control everything but you will have to setup all the animation yourself. When I think of a Paint drop animation, I am thinking of the classic crown splash, what exactly are you trying to achieve? "Paint splashes on window" is a bit vague.

Comment: I am sorry, for my bad explaination. What i want to do are actually paint drops, but they are supposed to behave kinda like slime. So, there is that one drop/mesh/sphere and it is supposed to hit a ceratain point, when it hits that point, that "drop" is supposed to explode and covers the camera view by that.

Comment: When you do Fluid simulations in Blender you set a Domain where the physics is calculated. If you set the camera position so that the Domain wall is close and set the viscosity correctly you will get the splash and splat result you are looking for.

Comment: And i can acutally let the fluid type look like a deformed sphere? Because when i think about, what you say, i will need a inflow as fluid type, which would look like a waterjet, that flys against that "Domain wall".

Comment: Can't i do that with the soft body physics, and if so, what do i need to do? I just want to do that with one mesh anyways. For me, it seems like, that fluid sims are the wrong way to do, what i want. I mean, how am i able to control a specific sphere with fluid sims?